# Drop-Shadow minimized in corner after scrolling

Tags: css

I have an issue where the drop shadow that I have for my images gets pushed to the top-left section of the div it encompasses.  The CSS for this section is

```
.shadowed img {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #222);
  filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #222);
}
```

This issue is fixed by scrolling down more and then back up, or just moving your mouse over the area.  It's just the section directly under where it disappears under the bottom of the display.  Any idea on why this would happen at all?

Edit: If you wish to see this in action, go to my [website](https://pokemondatabase.azurewebsites.net/pokemon), select a generation and then scroll down.

[image: Example]

Comment: Mh, i can't reproduce this issue. Which browser are you using?

Comment: My browser is Firefox